Weight Transfer for Clothes, Resetting Applied transformations?
I am currently transferring weight onto a character model separated by a skeleton & character model.
I  attached the item to the skeleton via Empty groups.
Prior to all of it I applied any transformation (all) to all objects, including changing the resting position to the current position instead of the T- Pose.
The issue occurs when I transfer weight via by name. The clothes resprings  up like this. In pose mode everything moves according to the body part but I am not sure how I can fix this.


